# Breaking rocks in Asterix

Tags: story-identification, asterix

I vaguely remember an Asterix comics book or animated film I watched in the 1990s where Obelix and Panoramix are depicted breaking rocks with hammers, possibly doing forced labor in a prison camp(?). Obelix uses a sledge hammer and huge swings while Panoramix uses a tiny hammer and tiny hits at a precise location. Both rocks break down into pieces.

What is the title of the book or film?

Comment: Obelix is a sculptor. Could that be what you're thinking of?

Comment: Maybe the scene was about the creation of a sculpture rather than forced labor; that I can't remember. But the main point was clearly opposing the strength of one and the wit of the other, yielding the same results. 
It still resonates with me when comes the time to evaluate the energy required to perform a task.

Comment: I think I recall this too, and am pretty sure it's from one of the comics (I've only seen two films - the animated Asterix in Britain, and the recent Asterix and the Magic Potion). I read the comics quite a lot in the early to mid 90's, and there are very few as far as I recall where Panoramix (or Getafix in his UK translations at the time at least) goes adventuring with Asterix and Obelix. May help narrow it down.

Comment: It would have to be a film, if you remember the druid as Panoramix. In the English published comics he's always been Getafix.

Comment: Wikipedia lists 10 animated Asterix films: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Asterix_films. Do you remember anything about the animation style? That might help narrow it down. Assuming you are referring to a film and not a book.

Comment: That would be 2D animation, not 3D. And it would be the original version in French. I don't remember any particular style otherwise. I fast forwarded through all the movies I could find on Youtube and I could not find that scene... Are there mini-episodes of 20 or 30 minutes out there?